# How do I add a button to the Experience Editor Ribbon?

Tags: experience-editor

I would like to add a button to the Experience Editor ribbon that will open a modal or new window with a set of fields from the context item.  I had some custom code to do this with the old Sheer UI ribbon but would like to implement this within the new Speak UI ribbon.  I have found Sitecore's documentation to create the button: [Customize the Experience Editor ribbon](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/the_editing_tools/the_experience_editor/customize_the_experience_editor_ribbon#_Create_a_new)

However, I'm having a hard time finding a good example of what to perform within the `execute` method of my custom javascript.

What javascript would I need to open a window that displays a pre-configured set of fields that exist on the context item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with version 8 or 8.1 it was changed how to add a button to experience button.
  Please follow next link to add new button to experience editor:

http://reyrahadian.com/2015/04/15/sitecore-8-adding-edit-meta-data-button-in-experience-editor/

Before it was very simple, you didn't need to add new code for editing hidden field:

https://blog.istern.dk/2012/05/21/running-sitecore-field-editor-from-a-command/

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to open a Field Editor dialog.  Unfortunately, SPEAK makes this much more complicated than it really should be.  This [blog post by Thomas Stern](https://blog.istern.dk/2015/03/02/running-sitecore-field-editor-from-a-speak-command-in-sitecore-experience-editor/) gives all the dirty details.

The executive summary is that you need to create a URL for the field editor dialog that has all of the parameters it needs like the list of fields, height, width, title, etc.  While you might be able to hard-code that URL into your JavaScript, it is generally preferable to generate it based on a settings item or as Thomas does by re-purposing a field on the button item.  To do that, you need to create a SPEAK request which will execute a method in a class that you will need to write.  You'll end up with like 4 files and a couple of items just to open a dialog.  Welcome to the world of SPEAK.